# How to randomly select a specific sequence from a list?

Tags: python

I have a list of hours starting from (0 is midnight).

```
hour = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]
```

I want to generate a sequence of 3 consecutive hours randomly. Example:

```
[3,6]
```

or

```
[15, 18]
```

or

```
[23,2]
```

and so on. random.sample does not achieve what I want!

```
import random    
hourSequence = sorted(random.sample(range(1,24), 2))
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why you don't want to generate random index and retrieve [index: index+2] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't exactly sure what you want, but probably

```
import random

s = random.randint(0, 23)

r = [s, (s+3)%24]

r
Out[14]: [16, 19]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** None of the other answers take in to consideration the possible sequence `[23,0,1]`

Please notice the following using `itertools` from python lib:

```
from itertools import islice, cycle
from random import choice

hours = list(range(24)) # List w/ 24h
hours_cycle = cycle(hours) # Transform the list in to a cycle
select_init = islice(hours_cycle, choice(hours), None) # Select a iterator on a random position

# Get the next 3 values for the iterator
select_range = []
for i in range(3):
    select_range.append(next(select_init))

print(select_range)
```

This will print sequences of three values on your `hours` list in a circular way, which will also include on your results for example the `[23,0,1]`.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. The flagged answer works as well and takes into consideration the option I wanted:
Examples:
[21, 0 ], [22,1] and [23, 2]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import random
hour = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]
index = random.randint(0,len(hour)-2)
l = [hour[index],hour[index+3]]
print(l)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. It works but will not give two options:
1) 23-2
2) 22-1

Answer (score 0):

You can get a random number from the array you already created `hour` and take the element that is 3 places afterward:

```
import random

def random_sequence_endpoints(l, span):
    i = random.choice(range(len(l)))
    return [hour[i], hour[(i+span) % len(l)]]

hour = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]
result = random_sequence_endpoints(hour, 3)
```

This will work not only for the above *hours list* example but for any other list contain any other elements.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If i = 23 will give 
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: You are right i missed that. Edited my answer, hope it's still helpful